After Upgrade SQL from 2017 to 2019 "Ambiguous paths" error when deploying tabular model database to Analysis Services in SQL Server 2019
"Ambiguous paths" error when deploying tabular model database to Analysis Services in SQL Server 2019 after upgrade from SQL Server 2017.
I tried following link but it for SQL 2017. I am looking same solution for W2019 after upgrade from W2017.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4040085-fix-ambiguous-paths-error-when-deploying-tabular-model-database-to-analysis-services-in-sql-server-2016-or-2017-b8828175-c565-cb54-43e8-bb72ce52dc93
